# Why doesn't this example ruby code print the result?

Tags: ruby, local-variables

I'm wondering why the code below doesn't print the movies that have more than 3 stars.

```
movie_ratings = {
  memento: 3,
  primer: 3.5,
  the_matrix: 5,
  truman_show: 4,
  red_dawn: 1.5,
  skyfall: 4,
  alex_cross: 2,
  uhf: 1,
  lion_king: 3.5
}

def good_movies
  puts movie_ratings.select {|movies, ratings| ratings > 3}
end
good_movies
```

Comment: It didn't run at all when I tried to run it (because inside a method created with def you can't see local variables such as movie_ratings created outside)

Comment: @FrederickCheung: That is the problem, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variable `movie_ratings` is not accessible in the method `good_movies`. Several approaches are available here:

1. Pass ratings as a parameter

   ```
   movie_ratings = {
     memento: 3,
     primer: 3.5,
     the_matrix: 5,
     truman_show: 4,
     red_dawn: 1.5,
     skyfall: 4,
     alex_cross: 2,
     uhf: 1,
     lion_king: 3.5
   }

   def good_movies(ratings)
     puts ratings.select {|movies, ratings| ratings > 3}
   end

   good_movies(movie_ratings)
   ```
2. Make ratings instance variable (instead of local variable)

   ```
   @movie_ratings = {
     memento: 3,
     primer: 3.5,
     the_matrix: 5,
     truman_show: 4,
     red_dawn: 1.5,
     skyfall: 4,
     alex_cross: 2,
     uhf: 1,
     lion_king: 3.5
   }

   def good_movies
     puts @movie_ratings.select {|movies, ratings| ratings > 3}
   end

   good_movies
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `movie_ratings` is not in the scope of the method. you should pass it as a parameter:

```
movie_ratings = {
  memento: 3,
  primer: 3.5,
  the_matrix: 5,
  truman_show: 4,
  red_dawn: 1.5,
  skyfall: 4,
  alex_cross: 2,
  uhf: 1,
  lion_king: 3.5
}

def good_movies movie_ratings
  puts movie_ratings.select {|movies, ratings| ratings > 3}
end
good_movies movie_ratings
# {:primer=>3.5, :the_matrix=>5, :truman_show=>4, :skyfall=>4, :lion_king=>3.5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because local variables cannot take scope into a method block. Change it to another type of variable, for example an instance variable, and it will work.

```
@movie_ratings = {
  memento: 3,
  primer: 3.5,
  the_matrix: 5,
  truman_show: 4,
  red_dawn: 1.5,
  skyfall: 4,
  alex_cross: 2,
  uhf: 1,
  lion_king: 3.5
}

def good_movies
  puts @movie_ratings.select {|movies, ratings| ratings > 3}
end
good_movies
```

Answer (score 1):

You should either pass `movie_ratings` to the method `good_movies` like this :

```
def good_movies(movie_ratings)
  puts movie_ratings.select {|movies, ratings| ratings > 3}
end
```

or make movie_ratings an instance variable like this:

```
@movie_ratings
```

and then inside the method use: `puts @movie_ratings.select {|movies, ratings| ratings > 3}`

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the following error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `movie_ratings' for main:Object
```

The reason is the method `good_movies` creates its own local scope, and it doesn't understand what `movie_ratings` is. You need to pass it to the method so that the method will understand what it is.

```
def good_movies(movies)
  return movies.select { |m, r| r > 3 }
end
```

Comment: Don't need `return` here.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been mentioned before you have to pass movie_ratings to the method as a parameter or make it instance variable.

But there is also a third option: make movie_ratings a constant variable. Just by capitalising the first letter (or the whole name, as preferred). Then the variable will be accessible by the method good_movies.

Everything you need to know about how they work: https://www.rubyguides.com/2017/07/ruby-constants/

```
MOVIE_RATINGS = {
  memento: 3,
  primer: 3.5,
  the_matrix: 5,
  truman_show: 4,
  red_dawn: 1.5,
  skyfall: 4,
  alex_cross: 2,
  uhf: 1,
  lion_king: 3.5
}

def good_movies
  puts MOVIE_RATINGS.select {|movies, ratings| ratings > 3}
end
good_movies
```